# Eigenvalues on the spectral radius of a non-negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory

Consider a square and non-negative matrix $A$, of dimension $n$, such that each row of $A$ has the same sum $d$. It is known that the spectral radius of $A$ is $d$.

Now, suppose that there are $m<n$ eigenvalues of $A$ such that $|\sigma_j| = d$, $j=1,\cdots,m$, that is, $A$ has $m$ eigenvalues on its spectral circle. My question is: Do they (the eigenvalues with modulus equals $d$) always comes uniformly distributed on the spectral circle of $A$, that is, do they can always be written as?
$$
\sigma_k = d \exp(2\pi ki/m), k=1,\cdots,m.
$$

The Perron-Frobenius theory asserts that if the graph $\mathcal{G}(A)$, with links given by $A$, is strongly connected then the result holds and $m$ is called the index of imprimitivity of $A$. But the Perron-Frobenius theory makes no assumption regarding special properties of $A$ as I'm assuming.

So, if someone can give a concrete assertation about this result I would appreciate. Many thanks!

Comment: Perron-Frobeius **theorem**, not "theory"

Comment: "Theory" is actually somewhat appropriate here because there is not just one theorem, there are several related ones.

Comment: Also, the usual term is "assertion", not "assertation".

Comment: Sorry for my English. It's not the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.  For instance, consider the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}A_1&0\\0&A_2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, where
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad A_2 = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}
$$
Then the $5$ eigenvalues of $A$ are all on the unit circle, but not "evenly distributed".

Comment: I see. But if in addition, we consider that the graph $\mathcal{G}(A)$ is connected, the answer is still no?

Comment: The answer is still no.   Consider $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}A_1&B\\0&A_2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ for any $B \neq 0$.

Comment: If you consider the same $A_1$ and $A_2$ as in your answer, then the property that every row has the same sum is not fulfilled, for any $B\neq0$.

Comment: Missed that bit. Then, I'm not sure.

Comment: If you ask for connected but not strongly connected, try
$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0\cr
                   0 &  0   & 1 & 0    & 0 & 0\cr
                   0 &  1   & 0 & 0   &   0 & 0\cr
                   0 &  0   & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr
                   0 &  0  &  0  & 0 & 0 & 1\cr
                   0 & 0  & 0   & 1 & 0 & 0\cr} $$

Comment: Nice. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $d = 1$ and $A$ is the transition matrix of a finite Markov chain.  The eigenvalues of absolute value $1$ are eigenvalues of the diagonal blocks of $A$ corresponding to the irreducible classes of recurrent states.
Each of these blocks has a certain period $p_j$, and its eigenvalues of  are all $p_j$'th roots of unity.

Comment: If $d>1$ then one can normalize the elements of $A$ to have row sum $1$ and the result still holds, right?